# Codenameone when I read the qrCode uzing Zxing on Android the application goes back to 'init' and 'start'

Tags: android, qr-code, android-lifecycle, codenameone

I am using Codenameone and ZXing to read a QRCode. When I call the Scanner, my mobile opens the QRCode reader application and I get to read the QRCode except that when android takes me back to my app it goes through init then start statuses. Which moves me back to the login form of my application instead of continuing filling the form that I was in.

Any help on what to do to stay in the same form? Is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
    EverproX.addMessage("Before Scan\n");
    CodeScanner.getInstance().scanQRCode(new ScanResult() {

       public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
            EverproX.addMessage("Scan Completed "+contents);
       }

       public void scanCanceled() {
            EverproX.addMessage("Scan Cancelled");
       }

       public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
            EverproX.addMessage("Scan Error "+errorCode+" "+message);
       }
   });
```

EverproX can be seen as a log class.

By analyzing our log we can say that as soon as we call the CodeScanner.getInstance().scanQRCode() the application is called for 'Destroy'. Then after the scanning is done it goes again through the init and start. It never goes into the scanComplete scanCanceled or scanError Callbacks.

Is it normal that the App is destroyed upon call of CodeScanner? Many thanks.

Comment: Read your logcat. It'll tell you why it's crashing.

Comment: A log file would help, since we don't have the context in which your application is running.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your codenameone project, you should find a class named (for example MyApp.java) based on your app's name, modify the code to read something like similar to this:

```
public class MyApp {

private Form current;

public void init(Object context) {
    // Pro users - uncomment this code to get crash reports sent to you automatically
    Display.getInstance().addEdtErrorHandler(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            evt.consume();
            Log.p("Exception in AppName version " + Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppVersion", "Unknown"));
            Log.p("OS " + Display.getInstance().getPlatformName());
            Log.p("Error " + evt.getSource());
            Log.p("Current Form " + Display.getInstance().getCurrent().getName());
            Log.e((Throwable) evt.getSource());
            Log.sendLog();
        }
    });
}

public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    new StateMachine("/theme");
}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
}

public void destroy() {
    current = null;
}
```

}

Comment: I would also add he should run the existing demos such as the code scan demo and the kitchen sink demo to verify.